# Can I use meshlab to make a turntable animation from a .ply file?

Tags: 3d, rotation, animated-gif, meshlab

I have no problem importing the file, I just am unsure if meshlab is the right program to make this animation. I essentially just want a gif or a video file that rotates a 3D object in the x-plane and then in the y-plane.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no function to create an animation built in to Meshlab, there is a way to create an animation manually. Use Filters->Mesh Layer->Matrix: Set from translation/rotation...". Choose the angle increment to be small and repeatedly press Apply, then Snapshot (snapshot is camera icon in the tool bar at the top) to save individual frames.

There are many on-line tools for joining png files together to create an animated gif e.g. [gifmaker.me](http://gifmaker.me/)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but in python [there is a library](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Basic/transformation.html) that could help you automate this:

```py
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("my_file.ply")

def rotate_view(vis):
    ctr = vis.get_view_control()
    ctr.rotate(10.0, 0.0) # rotates 10 degrees every frame
    
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries_with_animation_callback([pcd], rotate_view)
```

See [the open3d](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.7.0/tutorial/Advanced/customized_visualization.html) tutorial for more info